# Display event name from database in current date

Tags: php, tags

Display event name from database in current date.

This is my code:

```js
 <?php 
     $insum=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `log` AS event_today WHERE `date` = $currentdate");
     $d=mysql_fetch_assoc($insum);
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM log"); 
     $number=mysql_num_rows($query);                   
 ?>


<div class="inner">
<h3>
<?php
    echo " {$d['event_today']} / ";
    echo $number;
 ?></h3>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: query it inside your h3

Comment: Is `$currentdate` actually set to a value?

Comment: remove the `` in date

Comment: no sir it automatically get the current date

Answer (score 0):

`$currentdate` needs to quoted, and in a yyyy-mm-dd format

So

```
$insum=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `log` AS event_today WHERE `date` = '$currentdate'");
```

Note, this method of MySQLing has been depracated in place of `PDO` or `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

To get the date in a format that MySQL can understand (`YYYY-MM-DD`), use:

```
$currentdate = date('Y-m-d');
```

You also should use MySQLi rather than `mysql_*()`, as the old `mysql_*()` functions are now deprecated.